# How to get from Istanbul Airport (Atatürk) to Bursa, mid March, by bus and ferry?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, turkey, ferries, isl

I need to get from Atatürk Airport landing at around 6 to the port for the BUDO catamaran.

Would a bus or taxi be a better choice?

Also, which buses would be best and would I have to book in advance (preferably with fares and times)?

Comment: Which port exactly are you taking about? Is it the Yenikapi terminal?

Answer (score 1):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Istanbul/Bursa) comes in  handy for this:

They suggest 3 routes:

- Car Ferry via Yalova - $12-$15 (although you'll need a car) (~2.5 hours)
- Bus via Yalova - $24-26 (~4 hours)
- Train and Bus via Aksaray (~4.5 hours) $19-$22

which would be 'best' depends on you, your travel plans and time and money, but as a general rule - if you're not used to travelling in a new country, choose the option with fewest changes.